# setting up domain name

Tags: apache, hosting, dns

i'm new at webhosting. I'm trying to set up a small website and i have bought a domain name www.example.com. I have a vps running centos 5 with apache and direct admin. However i am not sure how to make the domain name i bought link to the ip address of my server, so that when someone types www.example.com it takes them to my website.

Also, is it difficult to set up an e-mail address such as me@www.example.com? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy a domain name, you need to tell the registrar which name servers you use. Probably your hosting provider did that for you. He also administers the name servers, but might give you limited permissions to modify your records. Ask him for details.

Comment: hi thx for reply. I don't quite follow... my hosting provider didn't do anything as i bought the domain name myself from another organisation...

Comment: That other organization should provide you with the means of pointing it to your server. Ask them.